# Scraping keeps getting an error just some of the times

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape recipe information off of allrecipes.com and save it in my database running on MySQL.

I first tried to get the information back through scraping with bs4, and some of the times it worked and some other times it didn't even though I changed nothing in the script. I kept getting these

```
recipe_serving = soup.find('span',class_='recipe-ingredients__header__toggles').meta['content']
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'meta'
```

messages that make absolutely no sense, because there definitely is a 'meta' attribute to this span tag, which is definitely not a NoneType object.
So I just kept running my script over and over, changing nothing in my script, until it started magically working just as I intended and I got the information I wanted.

But then when I added other scraping functions to get some other information (link to the main picture of the recipe) I started getting this 'meta' error message again and occasionally another error message that reads:

```
img_link = soup.find('div', class_='hero-photo__wrap').a.img['src']
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'
```

which, again, makes no sense, so I kept running my script until I eventually got the information I was trying to retrieve.

Now I'm scraping for a third detail, and I run them all at once, and the same thing happens until I eventually get the detail I wanted using this third scraping function, and I run into dozens of error messages that all read "NoneType has no 'name_of_tag' attribute", but it switches it up from time to time, I get this 'meta' one for like 6 times and then I get a 'div' one from another function and then the 'a' one, and I am running the same script over and over for about 30 minutes, still not getting the result I am looking for (the information has to be written into my database) because I keep hitting these nonsense error messages that mean nothing to me.

Here's a copy of my code:
https://repl.it/@HillaShx/scrapingintodb

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked this span is not generated dynamically or randomly ?

Comment: No, I haven't. How do I check that and what can I do about it?

Comment: You can scrap request the html page, save it locally and manually check if the elments you are looking for are in them. If not, the elements are generated dynamically, and you can come back to me if this is the case I would explain the different strategies :)

Comment: @HillaShahrabani View the page source in the browser and if the elements you are looking for aren't there, chances are the content is dynamically generated.

Comment: @BlueSheepToken Yeah, I just scraped the whole page and I can see all three tags in the right places. Anything else I should check?

Comment: I tried your code and I didn't found the error you've mentioned. Now the site is not responding anymore from my place (maybe a DDoS protection?). Btw, did you try using BS html parser instead of lxml ?

Comment: @manuel_b I wasn't aware that using html parser could make a difference, but now that you mentioned it I did try just now and I get the same outcome. What could be the reason we are getting different outcomes with the same code? maybe something to do with versions of either my parser or any of my other libraries?

Comment: I'm still having trouble retrieving information using bs4. I've downloaded all of the html pages I meant to scrape just to make it simpler and then it worked perfectly for a while and now it doesn't work, again. It is driving me mad, I hope someone here will have an idea as to what might cause this absurd issue. Thank you all anyway for trying to help!